# Como seleccionar 3 filas por cada fila

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla con Calls (llamadas), cada llamada tiene fecha de finalizacion que es EndTime. La llamada tiene los participantes en otra tabla que se llama ConferenceParticipant.
Tengo que hacer una query que me seleccione las llamadas y por cada una, las dos anteriores. Hay alguna manera de hacerlo sin cursores y que sea rapido ?

Por ejemplo, row1 seria la ultima llamada, y row2 y row3 las dos llamadas anteriores para ese worker.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo obtener las llamadas en orden descendiente por finalización asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando esta query:

```
SELECT TWC.TWCallSid, TWC.StartTime, TWC.EndTime, TWCP.TWWorkerSid from TWCall TWC
INNER JOIN TWConferenceParticipant TWCP ON TWCP.TWCallSid = TWC.TWCallSid
INNER JOIN TWWorker TWW ON TWW.Sid = TWCP.TWWorkerSid 
ORDER BY TWW.TWWorkerId, TWC.EndTime DESC
```

Estuve intentando hacerlo usando Tally tables pero no tuve exito:

```
WITH Tally AS
(
    SELECT TWC.TWCallSid, TWC.EndTime, TWCP.TWWorkerSid FROM TWCall TWC --, TWC.StartTime, TWC.EndTime, TWCP.TWWorkerSid
    INNER JOIN TWConferenceParticipant TWCP ON TWCP.TWCallSid = TWC.TWCallSid
    INNER JOIN TWWorker TWW ON TWW.Sid = TWCP.TWWorkerSid 
)


SELECT TWCallSid, 'row' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, rowNumber) AS 'row', TWWorkerSid FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Tally.TWWorkerSid ORDER BY Tally.EndTime DESC) AS rowNumber, Tally.TWCallSid, Tally.TWWorkerSid FROM (
        SELECT * FROM Tally
    ) as Tally
) as test2
WHERE test2.rowNumber <= 3
```

PEro me esta produciendo solo 17 resultados, nada que ver con lo necesitado. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx! Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Ahi lo edité, me olvide que era en español aca. gracias

Comment: uh esto podria salir con over... pero hay que trabajarla un poco....

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos? Es importante, saber el motor y la versión. Por otro lado si generas unos datos con unas cuantas pocas filas de ejemplo y el resultado a obtener, sería mucho más fácil, que alguien te diera la respuesta adecuada.

Comment: SQL Server 2019, con SQL Management studio 2018 estoy usando

Comment: Tienes que exponer un script con los datos y el resultado esperado. A priori, no parece muy dificil empleando la funcion de ventana lead. Pero sin un escenario claro y la salida esperada no tendrás respuestas adecuadas.

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)